# Proving this integral as a function of $t$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

So let $h$ be a function bounded by $M$, so that $|h|< M$.

Also let $g$ be a continuous and non-negative functions.

Define:

$$f(t) = \int_0^t g(u-t)h(u) du$$

How can I show $f(t)$ is continuous in $t$? I know that normal integrals are continuous (when the integrated function does not depend on $t$). And since $g$ is continuous it seems like it would be true. But I am struggling to show it.

I have been trying to show it using the normal $\epsilon, \delta$ definition by trying to find a bound above for

$$|f(t)-f(s)|$$

So that $|t-s| < \delta \implies |f(t)-f(s)| \leq \epsilon$, but when I try to do this, the upper bound I get might be negative, which means this is not necessarily true. This is not a homework question, I am working through some textbook proofs, and want to fill in the blanks that are omitted in the proofs as I really struggle with analysis.

I found a previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946083/is-this-integral-function-continuous) but I do not think it answers my question. As the bounds are not part of the function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\eqalign{|f(t) - f(s)| &= \left|\int_0^t g(u-t) h(u) \; du - \int_0^s g(u-s) h(u)\; du\right|\cr
&\le \left|\int_0^s (g(u-t) - g(u-s))h(u)\; du\right| +\left| \int_s^t g(u-t) h(u)\; du\right|}$$ 
Now use the fact that on a bounded interval, $g$ is bounded and uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thats what I got originally. But I don't understand how I can guarantee that the RHS won't make $\epsilon - RHS$ negative using the uniform continuity of $g$. Isn't it possible that $\epsilon - |\int_0^s \dots  du|$ will be negative for certain $s$?

Comment: If you choose $\delta > 0$ appropriately, you can make each term on the right less than $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Thus, uniform continuity says for any $\eta > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(y)|<\eta$.  Then $\int_0^s (g(u-t) - g(u-s)) h(u)\; du < \eta M s$.  So you want $\eta < \epsilon/(2Ms)$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you!